# Troubles with creating an event handler

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, handlers

Hey I'm new to using event handlers and the like and I'm having a few problems with getting one working
This is in my namespace:

```
public delegate void buttonChange(object sender, EventArgs e);
```

This is the form before main:

```
public static event buttonChange eventButtonChange;
```

Then within main I have:

```
buttonChangeListener listener = new buttonChangeListener();
eventButtonChange += new buttonChange(buttonChangeNeeded);
```

Then a procedure:

```
void buttonChangeNeeded(object sender, buttonChangeArgs e)
    {
        // The Program has moved a state forward
        switch (e.TheNumber)
        {
            case 1:
                // Probe has been purged
                this.SetBtnAutoCycle1(true);
                break;
            case 2:
                //First Auto-Cycle Complete
                this.SetBtnPerf(true);                    
                break;
            case 3:
                //Performance Test Complete
                this.SetBtnAutoCycle2(true);
                break;
            case 4:
                //Second Auto-Cycle Complete
                this.SetBtnReport(true);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
```

Then finally a separate classes:

```
public class buttonChangeArgs : EventArgs
{
    public readonly int TheNumber;

    public buttonChangeArgs(int num)
    {
        TheNumber = num;
    }
}
public class buttonChangeListener
{
    public void changeTheButton(object o, buttonChangeArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
            "The button should move down too: {0}",
            e.TheNumber);
    }
}
```

To be honest I've looked through a through tutorials and tried to emulate them but don't really understand them, including the MSDN guide, I'm studying at university but promised a family member I'd develop some software for them over summer and so far it's gone well but I've hit a brick wall.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared an delegate with second parameter of type `EventArgs`. However in your main you are subscribing to it with handler that does not accept `EventArgs` but rather its subclass. Compiler cannot make a conversion here.

You can solve this by declaring delegate to accept your specific arguments:

```
public delegate void buttonChange(object sender, buttonChangeArgs e);
```

Besides that most likely your `Main` is a static method (I assume you are writing a console application). In that case your usage of `buttonChangeNeeded` is not valid since it is not static (at least from what we can see).

Comment: Thank you, no it's a set of forms, hence I need something to change buttons... The reason I'm doing it is because I want to be able to dictate when the buttons become available on other forms, and couldn't think of another way to do it.  Any way thank you for you help.